# Using Lombok with Java 8 optional field. How to populate field with a builder

Tags: java, java-8, option-type, lombok

With the following piece of code, only the required fields are being populated when calling `OrderDto.builder().build()`

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class OrderDto{

@NotNull
private String id;

private Optional<String> size;

@NotNull
private String description;
```

How can I also populate the optional field to test this is working correctly?

Comment: taking an `Optional` as a parameter looks fishy, a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your field without the `Optional` and then rewrite the getter.

```
private String size;

private Optional<String> getSize() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(size);
}
```

This would be more elegant than having the optional in the constructor.